# Problem starting oracle XE on linxu after succesfull configure

Tags: linux, oracle

I have installed Oracle XE on linux mint, but it won't start.

when I do:

> sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c start

I get this back:

```
Starting Oracle Net Listener. 
Starting Oracle Database instance XE.
Oracle Database instance XE started.

Failed to start Oracle Net Listener using
/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/tnslsnr and Oracle Database 
/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/sqlplus.
```

Oracel configured without errors after I added localhost th /etc/hosts.

Now hosts look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ksb-Latitude-E6420

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts ::1     
ip6-localhost ip6-loopback fe00::0 ip6-localnet ff00::0
ip6-mcastprefix ff02::1 ip6-allnodes ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
```

How can I trouble shoot this?
I can't find any logfile.

BR Kresten

Comment: Probably no your issue, but why  do you have 2 separate lines for ip address 127.0.0.1?  With the second (that contains both qualified and unqualifed host name) you don't need the first - that contains only unqualified.

Comment: Isn't mint just a graphical desktop, with editions for various branches of linux?  I'm suspecting that you are tying to run oracle on a linux for which it was not designed .. like Ubuntu.  What is the underlyiing version of linux?  I'm also suspicious of your trying to start oracle components with a sudo command.  Oracle should not be installed by root, and so should not be started by root, once installed.  What do you get if you logon as user 'oracle' and simply issue 'lsnrctl start'?

Comment: You are all rigth in your assumptions. It's just a ordinary laptop computer with linux Mint. And I'm starting oracle with sudo.
If I login as oracel and do lsnrctl start I get: "not found".
Is this not possible? I just a developer in need of a database to do some basic testing. Is there a better way to do this? I don't have a server to install it onto.

Comment: Ok, after a bit of research I see that 'mint' is not just a desktop but is the actual linux.  But it is derived from Ubuntu, which is a branch of linux for which oracle was _not_ designed, is not certified, and is not supported.  The usual soluiton, and the one I use on my Ubuntu laptop, is to install oracle VIrtualBox.  Then use that to create a vm and install Oracle Linux on that.  I write about it extensively at https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/category/personal-test-systems/

Comment: It will be a learning experience for sure, but no learning is ever wasted.  The more you know about anything helps with everytyhing else, and that is especially true about anything in it.  FWIW, the setup I describe (oracle on a VM under Vbox, on an Ubuntu host) is what I used for all of the demos on my blog.